# Direct upgrade of RTM OS version to Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have HTC Trophy with build 7.0.7004.0 - RTM version, unlocked for development.

Now I would like to upgrade to Mango and have the following questions:

1. Can I upgrade directly from RTM to Mango? I know there have been other updates in the past (e.g. NoDo), but I did not install any of them, I still have the original OS I got with the purchase of the device. Can I upgrade directly to Mango or will I have to run pre-Mango updates before Mango update?
2. Will Mango update lock my device again? Or will it remain unlocked?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mango update will take care of installing previous updates if required -- even uninstalling previous updates if required (e.g., it will remove pre-release versions of Mango) -- and install the Mango bits. As directed, it may require more than one reboot cycle before you're done, and can take a long time depending on what needs to get added or removed. Don't get overly excited and disconnect the phone just because you see it restart (like I did the first time : ).

Your developer unlocked device stays developer unlocked after upgrading to Mango. Whoopie!